# Django: Facebook Bot, send automatic messages

Tags: python, django, facebook, python-3.x, bots

Hello my question is how I can send automatic messages to my users by Facebook with a bot, I do my bot with this tutotial: https://abhaykashyap.com/blog/post/tutorial-how-build-facebook-messenger-bot-using-django-ngrok
My aplication is an intelligent security house system so I want to send a message when, for example, the levels of temperature are so high or something like that, the only thing that I want to know is this part of send the message to the correct FB user.

Comment: show your code.